# using grep in the perl script

Tags: perl

I have a perl script, such as:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;

    my @vars = split(" ", "aaa bbb");
    my @list = split(" ", "aaa");

    foreach(@vars) {
        if ( grep(/$_/, @list)) {
            print "1\t";
        }else{
            print "0\t";
        }
    }
```

I was hoping it gives "1   0" in return, but it is always "1 1". Does anyone know why ?  I am using perl 5.8.8.

Thanks.

Chun

Answer (score 7):

Because you are abusing the `$_` variable.

Inside the expression of a `grep EXPR, LIST` construction, `$_` is aliased to an element of the list and the expression is evaluated. The previous value of `$_` is not restored until the end of the `grep` statement.

Since a naked `/.../` expression is equivalent to `$_ =~ /.../`, your `grep` statement is just

```
grep $_ =~ /$_/, @list
```

with `$_` aliased to an element of `@list`, and which is true for most normal values of `$_`.

The lesson is to not make `$_` do too much work for you. Say

```
foreach $var (@vars) {
    if ( grep(/$var/, @list)) {
        print "1\t";
    }else{
        print "0\t";
    }
}
```

instead. Anyone who looks at your code six months from now (including your future self) will thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much !  I have a feeling this "$_" was not interpret the way I had thought during this "grep" call. I  just could not find out why it happens that way.